# Blocking requests to a specific subdomain made by a Chrome browser extension

Tags: linux, google-chrome, dns

There's a Chrome browser extension that I use that collects personal data. I like the extension, but I want to block its ability to collect my personal data.

I was previously blocking its data collection by blocking the data collection subdomain with the `/etc/hosts` file, but it seems that Chrome now has its own internal DNS lookup - maybe related to DNS-over-HTTPS. It seems like a bad idea to disable this feature for security reasons.

Some thoughts:

- I could potentially unpack and edit the extension to remove the data collection (would need to do this for every update).
- Using uBlock Origin or similar wouldn't work because it can't block requests made by (the service workers of) browser extensions.
- GPT-4 recommends that I set up a cron job to intermittently translate the data collection subdomain to the associated IP and block it with iptables/ufw. This seems kinda arduous and I'm not sure it is full-proof because their IP could change at any moment. That said, an absolutely "full proof" solution isn't really required.

So I'm wondering if there are any other options here? Seems like a simple task, but the viable solutions seem fairly involved.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an iptables string-based filter, where iptables does not apply rules
to IP addresses but instead to a matching pattern in the request.

Example (untested) :

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string sub.domain.com --algo kmp -j DROP
```

The weakness of this filter type is that if the extension uses directly
the IP address, it might be bypassed in some cases.

For an analysis of the weaknesses, see the article
[That’s Why Iptable Is Not A Good Fit For Domain Name?](https://blog.opstree.com/2020/09/15/is-iptable-a-good-fit-for-a-domain-name/)

Comment: Thanks Harry - would this work for encrypted DNS though - e.g. DNS-over-HTTPS?

Comment: It's hard or even impossible to block DoH protocol. You may need to setup your own DNS server in LAN for that.